# Cons of using Django Dev Server in production

Tags: python, django

I am writing an application which will be used by  single user in production. One of my requirements was to be able to change settings.py on the fly ( and have them reflected without requiring a server restart )

I am considering the use of the dev server though I am aware that it is **never** recommended.

**Question** : Can someone please point me to some documentation about what are the cons of using the Django Dev server ( my application is a single user application and hence I am considering this ) in production ?

Is there readily available data on ?

- Reliability - how frequently does it need to be restarted on an average ?
- Limit on the amount of request data it can handle ?
  and so on .

P.S. I know why a production server ( apache mod_wsgi ) is good. I am looking for some detailed info about why the Django Dev server is bad for production.

Thanks,
Shoubhik

Comment: That requirement is unfulfillable. Not even the dev server can do it (and the dev server will restart hard, without the control you get from a real web server).

Comment: If your settings are going to change often, store it in the DB. If you want simplicity of deployment, look into gunicorn - it's shockingly simple to launch.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 
"and the dev server will restart hard" >> That is the info I was looking for . How frequently? And yes, you can change settings.py on the fly when the dev server is used - it gets instantly picked up.

Comment: @sbose - yes it instantly gets picked up, but when it picks them up it will 'restart hard' - that's what Ignacio was referring to.